# How to configure a sonar-project.properties file for code coverage?

Tags: maven, properties, configuration, sonarqube

Current my scanner is running through and only scanning the parent and skipping the rest of my nested files. If I run sonarlint (using the cli and specifying some test and source files) , it tries to analyze 37k files instead of the few I need. I have been able to skip ~3k files by adding the `<sonar.skip>true</sonar.skip>` property to a pom file. However, I still can't configure the project to run across certain sub-folders and print out some kind of code coverage test. (Is JaCoCo needed for the latest version(6.3,0)? Or can code-coverage be handled through some configuration?).

Answer (score 0):

If Sonar seems to be analyzing too many files, it is probably because you had not set the `sonar.sources=src/main/java` in your `sonar-project.properties` file, so it defaults to the basedir and includes everything.
SonarQube can't do code-coverage itself, it just reports on coverage-reports from a tool like JaCoCo. It is funny they don't clarify these things in https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner --but with enough digging, you can find good info on that site.